# Add Multiple Apache Document Root under one port

Tags: apache, document, root

I'm looking to have 1 domain point to different drives in my pc.

I've got my document root on D:\ working fine on port 80.

But I also want drive E:\ to show when I load my domain.

I understand I can use virtual hosts on different ports but thats not what I want because I want everything visible under the single domain of the root folder when I load www.example.com.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot have more than one domain root.
You can use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) to configure other file system paths

for example, you could have:

```
Alias /working d:/working
Alias /other e:/
```